# Подключение к WCF-сервису, блок Security

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

Добрый день всем. Пытаюсь подключиться к WCF-сервису, используется стандарт WS-Security. Для подписи запросов используется сертификат:

```
<clientCredentials>
    <clientCertificate x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"
                       storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                       storeName="My"
                       findValue="Тестовый НБКИ - 2016-07"/>
    <serviceCertificate>
        <authentication certificateValidationMode="None" />
    </serviceCertificate>
</clientCredentials>
```

Вот сама точка подключения:

```
  <endpoint address="https://ips.rosminzdrav.ru/5358bf30e7897"
   behaviorConfiguration="ipsErBeh" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="newBinding"
   contract="ipsWorkMisService.misInterface" name="ipsWorkEndPoint"/>
```

И используемый binding:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="newBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
             messageEncoding="Text">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"> 
            <message clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

В блок Security докидывается необходимое:

```
ipsWorkMisService.misInterfaceClient ms = new misInterfaceClient("ipsWorkEndPoint");

if (security != null)
{
    X509SecurityTokenParameters tokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
    tokenParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
    tokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
    security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(tokenParameters);
    security.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.SignedEncrypted.Add(new UserNameSecurityTokenParameters());
}
ms.Endpoint.Binding = new CustomBinding(elements.ToArray());
```

Но при попытке подключения сервер выдаёт ошибку "Проверка блока security: не найден элемент header\TransportHeader". Просьба подсказать: в чем может быть дело? Элемент header на месте, насколько я понимаю.
Заранее спасибо за ответы!

Comment: А как же _wsHttpBinding_ используемый, если в _endpoint_ задано `binding="basicHttpBinding"`? И имя в одном месте `newBinding`, а в другом `BasicHttpBinding_IService`. Не сходится что-то.

Comment: Прошу прощения, данные не по той точке скинул. Поправил.

Comment: Т.е., исходя из конфигурации (если я правильно понял), сервер проверяет что за клиент к нему подключается (задан _clientCertificate_), а клиент не проверяет к тому ли серверу он подключается (сертификат сервера не указан), верно? Режим безопасности, однако, задан _TransportWithMessageCredential_. Не уверен, что можно использовать режимы _Transport_ и _TransportWithMessageCredential_, не указывая сертификат сервера. Могу, впрочем, ошибаться.

Comment: Не всегда требуется указывать сертификат сервера. Во всяком случае, wshttpbinding того не требует.